# How to play video file in MPMOviePlayer?

Tags: iphone

I have implementing uITabbar application in which i want to play video file.Video file is playing but not seen.And simulator is Landscapmode bu MPMoviePlayer in Potrait mode.How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to play the mp4 format.Because MPMoviePlayer Controller does not support many formats like avi.Here is the code which i implement.Hope it will help you and download any mp4 video file to play.

```
 NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"SoundFileName" ofType:@"mp4"];   
    //NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    NSURL *fileURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath]retain];
    player =    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [fileURL release];

    [player play];
```